# Convert Out-of-bag (OOB) estimate to quad weighted kappa score

Tags: cross-validation, gbm

Is there a way to directly calculate an approximate quad weighted kappa measure from an OOB estimate, obtained from a gradient boosting model with subsampling without going through cross validation?